# How can I show the cents with R3 money?

Tags: currency, precision, rebol, bcd, rebol3

The online documentation promises this

```
  probe to-money 123
  $123.00
```

http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes/money.html

I get this

```
  probe to-money 123
  $123
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation you see is a copy of R2 documentation. It still does not reflect the current state in R3.

In R3 you can have both $123 as well as $123.00, have you tried?

This looks like a more accurate documentation:

http://www.rebol.net/wiki/Money

Answer (score 4):

```
>> round/to to money! 123 $.01
== $123.00
```